# How to seperate imdb id from the imdb movie link

Tags: php, imdb

I want to separate IMDb id from the link

my php code is this

```
<?php print $movie_info[0]->imdb_link; ?>
```

the URL seems like this on every page .

https://imdb.com/title/tt1206885

i want to show this id separate from the url on my page => tt1206885

please help me

i try but fail to extract the id

```
<?php if($movie_info[0]->imdb_link){?> 
ID <?php $str = explode("/",$movie_info[0]->imdb_link); 
   /* if url in php variable then $str = explode("/",$imdb_id); */ 
   print $str[count($str)-2];
?>">
<?php }?>
```

Comment: `basename('https://imdb.com/title/tt1206885')` will give `tt1206885`.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$link_array = explode('/', $movie_info[0]->imdb_link);
$id = end($link_array);
```

Comment: Don't answer duplicates, plus this answer is not explained at all.

Comment: @GrecoJonathan I wrote my answer 1 hour before the question was marked as duplicate ;)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: @CodyKL It's a basic question about a basic function in PHP, of course it's a duplicate (when your about to answer, a basic research before can help identify if it's a duplicate). Your solution is not explained because it's basic. That's make a poor quality answer for a poor quality question. And even if we ignore the fact that is a duplicate, your answer is still poor quality because unexplained